# How can I connect to the IB TWS platform from Mathematica?

Tags: java

TWS is the trading platform of Interactive Brokers. Accessing it programmatically could be useful for various purposes. How could I access it from Mathematica ?

Answer (score 10):

Here's a minimal example using the Java API of IB. Anything else can be done in theory by analogy. It works in Windows, but should work on other platforms as well as it's using Java.

Results are displayed in the Mathematica messages window.

**Prerequisite**
Read the beginning of https://www.interactivebrokers.com/download/JavaAPIGettingStarted.pdf , download the API and export the source\JavaClient project provided into a JAR file. You can do this in Eclipse for example, which is easy as the provided source code is an Eclipse project.

**References**
https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/api_Left.htm
https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/tws/twsguide_Left.htm
Api calls' examples: http://tradingbot.blogspot.fr/2009/07/proof-of-concept-8-of-8g-complex.html
Overview of the API functions:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IBrokers/vignettes/IBrokersREFCARD.pdf
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IBrokers/IBrokers.pdf

```
Needs["JLink`"]
ReinstallJava[ClassPath->"yourPath\\twsJar.jar"] ;

LoadJavaClass["java.util.Collections"];
emptyList=Collections`emptyList[];

LoadJavaClass["com.ib.client.TickType"];

(*Defining some interfaces (implementations of abstract methods) for eWrapper, look at the AnyWrapper and EWrapper class for a list of interfaces.*)  
(*The main thing to understand is that the arguments of these Mathematica functions ARE the results, so you can do whatever you want with them.*)  
(*You can modify these functions even after eWrapper has been defined, which makes development easier.*)
error[m___]:=Print@{"error",m};
tickPrice[(*int*)tickerId_,(*int*)field_,(*double*)price_,(*int*)canAutoExecute_]:=Print@{"tickPrice",tickerId,TickType`getField[field],price};
tickOptionComputation[(*int*) tickerId_,(*int*) field_,(*double*) impliedVol_,(*double*) delta_,(*double*) optPrice_,(*double*) pvDividend_,(*double*) gamma_,(*double*) vega_,(*double*) theta_,(*double*) undPrice_]:=Print@{"tickOptionComputation",tickerId,TickType`getField[field],impliedVol};

(*Wrapper needed for replies from the server, each function in the wrapper can be called by the client upon an answer from the server and passed to a Mathematica implementation*)
eWrapper=ImplementJavaInterface["com.ib.client.EWrapper",{"error"->"error","tickPrice"->"tickPrice","tickOptionComputation"->"tickOptionComputation"}];
eWrapper@error["hello"];

eClient=JavaNew["com.ib.client.EClientSocket",eWrapper];
eClient@eConnect["127.0.0.1",7496,0];
(*press yes in TWS to accept the connection*)
eClient@isConnected[];

contract=JavaNew["com.ib.client.Contract"];
contract@mUsymbol="ES";
contract@mUsecType="FOP";
contract@mUexpiry="20141219";
contract@mUstrike=2000.0;
contract@mUright="P";
contract@mUmultiplier="50";
contract@mUexchange="GLOBEX";
contract@mUcurrency="USD";

tickerId=0;
genericTicklist=""(*"100"*);
snapshot=True(*False*);
eClient@reqMktData[tickerId,contract,genericTicklist,snapshot,emptyList]
```

Comment: Could you provide some additional pointers?  Even something as trivial as compilation is a challenge for non Java programmers.  I read the Java API documentation and it seems relatively straightforward, once I get the initial setup done.

Comment: Two years I wrote this post already ... Time goes fast. I've spent so much time implementing a bridge between IB and MM, now that it works, I'm not even thinking about it anymore. The biggest difficulty is that many things are not documented by IB, the only way to understand how it works is by trial and error.

Comment: Do you distribute this code?

Comment: No I don't currently.